# Redirect to HTTPS from my Amazon Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl, ruby-on-rails, amazon-elb

I have a rails app on 2 EC2 Instances running nginx behind an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer. I'd like to force HTTPS, which was working fine before I added in the Load Balancer. Now I can't quite figure out how to do it.

My load balancer has 2 listeners: 80 to 80 and 443 to 80 (with an ssl cert).

I tried adding the following rewrite rule to the nginx config, but it didn't seem to work:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time if you forward 443 to 443.

Comment: You know, I had already tried that and got an error. So I tried again and realized what I did incorrectly last time: I typed in port 443 but didn't actually select https from the "Instance Protocol" drop-down. This fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we've been able to solve this doing the following:

Keep your ELB configured as stated (listening on boty 80 and 443, and forwarding traffic to instances on port 80)

Then in `application_controller.rb` do something similar to:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl if: :ssl_required?

  # rest of your code here

  private
  def ssl_required?
    # If we came in through the load-balancer, this header will be present
    if request.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto'].present? && !request.ssl?
      return true
    end
    return false 
  end
end
```